# How to loop through nested python dictionary with below structure?

Tags: python-3.x, collections

I have nested dictionary with below structure. Like key `values`, there might be multiple keys like `values1`, `values2`. I am looking for `random1` and `random2` strings. If exists, then have to check if `val` exists or not.

```
d = {"values": [
        {
          "name": "A1234",
          "description": "A1234-Description ",
          "random1": {
            "abcd": {
              "val": 1
            }
          },
          "random2": {
            "abcd": {
              "val": -1
            }
          }
        },
        {
        "name": "A4567",
          "description": "A4567-Description ",
          "random1": {
            "abcd": {
              "val": 1
            }
          },
          "random2": {
            "abcd": {
              "val": -1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "B1234",
          "description": "B1234-Description ",
        }
    ]}
```

**Code:**

```
for i in d["values"]:
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k in ("random1", "random2") and "abcd" in v1:
           if len(v1["abcd"]) != 0:
              if "val" in v1["abcd"]:
                  print("Found")
              else:
                  print("Not found")
           else:
               print("empty")
```

I believe that there's no shortcut to loop through to dictionary. But definitely there should be some techniques/optimisation to do this (reducing multiple for/if loops)

Can anyone please guide me, if it can be done by using collections etc

Comment: What is your desired output? A `Found, Not Found, empty` for each `randonm[12] -> abcd`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl : For each random1 or random2, 'val' found or not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive algorithm to go through the arborescence of the Dictionary

```
def recursive_iter(obj, keys=()):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            yield from recursive_iter(v, keys + (k,))
    elif any(isinstance(obj, t) for t in (list, tuple)):
        for idx, item in enumerate(obj):
            yield from recursive_iter(item, keys + (idx,))
    else:
        yield keys, obj
```

Here you can print the result

```
for keys, item in recursive_iter(d):
    print(keys, ' -> ', item)
```

Which displays :

```
('values', 0, 'name')  ->  A1234
('values', 0, 'description')  ->  A1234-Description 
('values', 0, 'random1', 'abcd', 'val')  ->  1
('values', 0, 'random2', 'abcd', 'val')  ->  -1
('values', 1, 'name')  ->  A4567
('values', 1, 'description')  ->  A4567-Description 
('values', 1, 'random1', 'abcd', 'val')  ->  1
('values', 1, 'random2', 'abcd', 'val')  ->  -1
('values', 2, 'name')  ->  B1234
('values', 2, 'description')  ->  B1234-Description
```

EDIT:

```
for keys, item in recursive_iter(d):
    if "val" in keys and "abcd" in keys:
        print("FOUND\n", keys, ' -> ', item)
    elif "val" not in keys and "abcd" in keys:
        print("NOT FOUND\n", keys, ' -> ', item)
```

Comment: we have to ensure that "val" is for "abcd" of 'random1' or 'random2' or both.

Comment: why is that check item == 1 and item == -1 ?

Comment: whether val = 1 or -1, just to check if "val" exists for "abcd" of 'random1' or 'random2' or both

Comment: If in dictionary order, if anything apart from 'random1'  and  'random2' in d["values"][index].keys(), shouldn't bother. Should consider, if it's only 'random1' 'random2'

Comment: I edited. Actually, since your query is not about recursive exploration, and if your Dictionary is always in this format, your script is already good. You can skip the second `for` loop and incorporate in your `if` statement : `if 'random1' in i and 'abcd' in i['random1']:` `if 'random2' in i and 'abcd' in i['random2']:` `if 'random1' not in i and  'random2' not in i:`